# Cannot Save Data in my database using a DataGridView

Tags: c#

I have made an application that can add,view,update and delete data from a database using a DataGridView. I have made separate forms for each operation using DGV. In update form I'm not able to update or edit data DGV and my data is not stored in the database from DGV. Please tell me the correct code. Its my code

```
    public Update()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    SqlConnection sql_con;
    SqlCommand sql_cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter Sql_ad;
    SqlCommandBuilder sql_cb;
    DataTable dt;
    DataSet ds;
    string connect_string;

    private void Update_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

        connect_string = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\form\form\EmployeeDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";   

        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ds_EmployeeDB.emp_info' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.emp_infoTableAdapter.Fill(this.ds_EmployeeDB.emp_info);


        string select_cmd = "SELECT * FROM emp_info";
        sql_con = new SqlConnection(connect_string);
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd = new SqlCommand(select_cmd,sql_con);
        Sql_ad = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_cmd);
        sql_cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(Sql_ad);
        ds = new DataSet();
        Sql_ad.Fill(ds,"emp_info");
        dt=ds.Tables["emp_info"];
        sql_con.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }

    private void button_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string select_cmd = "SELECT * FROM emp_info where f_name='" + textBox_Search.Text + "'";

        sql_con = new SqlConnection(connect_string);
        dt = new DataTable();
        Sql_ad = new SqlDataAdapter(select_cmd, sql_con);
        Sql_ad.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }  

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }

    private void button_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string update_query = "UPDATE emp_info SET " +
            "f_name = '" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "' ," +
            "l_name = '" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "' ," +
            "father_name = '" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "' ," +
            "education = '" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "' ," +
            "institute = '" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "' ," +
            "address = '" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString() + "' ," +
            "phone = '" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString() + "' ," +
            "cinc = '" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString() + "' ," +
            "WHERE '" + textBox_Search.Text + "'";

        sql_con = new SqlConnection(connect_string);
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd = new SqlCommand(update_query, sql_con);
        Sql_ad = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_cmd);
        sql_cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(Sql_ad);
        ds = new DataSet();
        Sql_ad.Fill(ds, "emp_info");
        dt = ds.Tables["emp_info"];
        sql_con.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void button_Cancle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by _not able to_ exactly? You get any exception or error message? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: means at run time my code breaks and before breaking, previously my data is not storing in database